# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.bookstore.entity.DetailOrder.books in com.bookstore.entity.Book.detailOrders

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I have a mapping problem in two classes named for `DetailOrder` and `Book`.

The issue has shown below.

> Initial SessionFactory creation failed.
>  
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: `mappedBy` reference an unknown target entity property: com.bookstore.entity.DetailOrder.books in com.bookstore.entity.Book.detailOrders

How can I fix it?

The classes as shown below.

**DetailOrder Class**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
private Book book;
```

**Book Class**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "book", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<DetailOrder> detailOrders = new HashSet<DetailOrder>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error message says that you are trying to map books (in plural). try to clean your project.